# How to conduct unconditional quantile regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, cran, quantile-regression

The only package I know that does unconditional quantile regression in R is uqr. Unfortunately, it's been removed from CRAN. Even though I can still use it, its functionality is limited (e.g., does not conduct significance tests or allow to compare effects across quantiles). I'm wondering if anyone knows how to conduct UQR in R, with either functions they wrote or some other means.

Comment: If you're not interested in a Stata solution, tagging with that name is a distraction.

Comment: I have posted the UQR package on GitHub and fixed up a few things. It still could use a lot of work. https://github.com/brandones/uqr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many limitations in terms of test and asymptotic theory regarding unconditional quantile regressions, especially if you are thinking on the version proposed in Firpo, Fortin, and Limeaux (2009) "Unconditional quantile regressions".

The application, however, is straightforward. you need only 2 elements:

1. the unconditional quantile (estimated with any of your favorite packages).
2. the density of the outcome at the quantile you got in (1)

After that, you apply the RIF function:

$$RIF(q) = q(t)+\frac{t-1(y<=q(t)}{f(q(t))}$$

Once you have this, you just use that instead of your dep variable, when you write your "lm()" function. And that is it.
HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try to implement this in R. To follow up on what you said, do you have any references on UQRs limitations? I've been searching for this, but no one has seemed to cover it. A more elaborate explanation of this would also be much appreciated.

Comment: FFL(2009) indicate that the main limitation is the estimation of standard errors (since they depend on an estimated parameter (the density). The other one is that UQR is based on local linear approximations. So may not be useful for, say, analyzing treatment effects. Finally, there is only limited literature on addressing problems of endogeneity and sample selection. if you search for "recentered influence function" you will find a Stata paper that describes some of the problems with references you may find useful.